# How can I get an image to move across the browser horizontally from right to left?

Tags: javascript

I have successfully made fish1 and fish2 move across the screen, but i am having a hard time figuring out how to get fish3 to move from right to left. Seeing how its facing to the left, I don't want it to swim backwards. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Fish Tanks</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS
var fish1Position = 0;
var fish2Position = 0;
var fish3Position = 99;
var horizontal = [];
var fillPosition = 10;
var num = 100;
for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        horizontal[i] = fillPosition;
        fillPosition += 10;
}

function fish1Swim() {
        document.getElementById("fish1").style.left = horizontal[fish1Position] + "px";
        ++fish1Position;
        if (fish1Position == num) {
                fish1Position = 0;
}
var tim1 = setTimeout(fish1Swim, 100);
}
function fish2Swim(){
        document.getElementById("fish2").style.left = horizontal[fish2Position] + "px";
         ++fish2Position;
         if (fish2Position == num) {
                 fish2Position = 0;
}
var tim2 = setTimeout(fish2Swim, 200);
}

function fish3Swim() {
     document.getElementById("fish3").style.left = horizontal[fish3Position] + "px";
     ++fish3Position;
     if (fish3Position == num) {
fish3Position = 99;
}
var tim3 = setTimeout(fish3Swim, 300);
}

function startSwimming() {
        fish1Swim();
        fish2Swim();
        fish3Swim();
}

// STOP HIDING FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startSwimming();">
<p><span id="fish1" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px"><img src="fish1.gif" alt="Image of a fish" /></span></p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p><span id="fish3" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:100px"><img src="fish3.gif" alt="Image of a fish" /></span></p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p><span id="fish2" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top 150px"><img src="fish2.gif" alt="Image of a fish" /></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just want to decrement the position, so:

```
--fish3Position;
```

instead of `++fish3Position;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Of course the solution had to be something simple. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, it moves to the left just fine, but the fish3 image stops and does not reset as the others do.

Comment: @Justin: That's correct, you have to check whether it is `0` and then set it back to `99`. So `fish3Postion == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

For browsers that support CSS3 transforms you should be able to add `style="transform:rotateY(180deg);"` to the fish3 img tag.

If you want your fish to swim back & forth, you may want to use an image editing program to create mirror images and swap left <-> right handed versions when a fish reaches the border of the viewport.  This technique would also help ensure that older browsers (without CSS3 transform support) will display properly.

Also, [this link](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/) might worth having a look at to learn more about (and test browser support for) CSS3 transforms.